# reactjs, sending props from one component to another

Tags: reactjs

I want to send props from component A to component B. How can I do it?
By the way I'm using `react.lazy()`.

```
import React from 'react';

const CustomerList = React.lazy(() => 
import('./views/CustomerList/CustomerList'));
const CustomerDebt = React.lazy(() => 
import('./views/CustomerDebt/CustomerDebt'));
const routes = [
  { path: '/', exact: true, name: 'Home page' },
  { path: '/customerlist', name: 'Debt list', component: CustomerList},
  { path: '/customerdebt', name: 'Customer Debt', component: CustomerDebt},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I never use React.lazy. But I can suggest for you one way. 
use HOC to pass props.
Create HOC:

```
   const LazyHOC = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
      <Suspense fallback={...}>
         <Component {...rest} />
      </Suspense>
   )
```

Import your Component:

```
   const CustomerList = React.lazy(() => import('./views/CustomerList/CustomerList'));
   const CustomerDebt = React.lazy(() => import('./views/CustomerDebt/CustomerDebt'));
```

Wrap Component with HOC:

```
   const LazyCustomerList = props => <LazyHOC component={CustomerList} {...props}/>
   const LazyCustomerDebt = props => <LazyHOC component={CustomerDebt} {...props}/>
```

And you can pass props like this:

```
   const routes = [
  { path: '/', exact: true, name: 'Home page' },
  { path: '/customerlist', name: 'Debt list', component: <LazyCustomerList props={...} />},
  { path: '/customerdebt', name: 'Customer Debt', component: <LazyCustomerDebt />},
```